# Display two strings, one vertically and one horizontally on Python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I want to print two strings formatted in a way that one is horizontally printed and the other vertically. To get something like this (sorry, stackoverflow makes it seemingly impossible to write vertical words on questions!)

```
m     o   n   t   y  p   y  t   h   o    n

e

x

c

e

l

l

e

n

t
```

Currently my code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for word in "montypython":
print(word,end='')
for l1 in 'excellent':
    print (l1)
```

However, this leads to mostly vertical prints of `excellent`, with a few letters having letters from `montypython` attached (it's kind of difficult to describe!)

Answer (score 3):

```
def print_words(first, second):
    print(first)
    for letter in second:
        print(letter)
```

Example

```
>>> print_words('montypython', 'excellent')
montypython
e
x
c
e
l
l
e
n
t
```

Or if you want to space the horizontal letters out

```
def print_words(first, second):
    print(' '.join(first))
    for letter in second:
        print(letter)

>>> print_words('montypython', 'excellent')
m o n t y p y t h o n
e
x
c
e
l
l
e
n
t
```

Comment: +1 I've learned that `join` takes strings too. I think you should make `for letter in second` : `for letter in ' '.join(second)`, to make it exactly like the provided output.

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib no need, could just have `print(letter,end='\n\n')`

Answer (score 0):

No need for loop or `join()`, just let Python3's `print` do it's thing:

```
def print_words(first, second):
    print(*first, sep=" " * 3, end="\n" * 2)
    print(*second, sep="\n" * 2)

print_words('montypython', 'excellent')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
m   o   n   t   y   p   y   t   h   o   n

e

x

c

e

l

l

e

n

t
```